# Faire causatif : quel pronom ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, constructions-causatives

Est-ce qu'on dirait: « Ce que je les ai fait manger » ou « Ce que je leur ai fait manger » ? On utilise le pronom du complément d'objet direct pour indiquer les personnes auxquelles on fait faire quelque chose, et le pronom du complément d'objet indirect quand le verbe après faire ne prend pas d’objet direct.

Comment: Je ne comprends pas bien l'objet de la question. Quel est le rapport avec de completement d'objet du verbe après faire ?

Answer (score 7):

Ce que tu cherches est vraisemblablement la deuxième forme. Mais en fait, les deux formes sont correctes grammaticalement, pour des raisons très différentes. La première est une phrase complète, la deuxième n'en est pas une.

1. Exemple d'utilisation avec *leur* :

   > J'ai fait manger des bananes *à* ces messieurs.
   >   Les bananes, c'est **ce que je *leur* ai fait manger**.

   Le pronom *leur* est l'équivalent de *à eux*, c'est le pronom pour un complément d'objet indirect.
2. Exemple d'utilisation avec *les* :

   > J'ai fait manger ces messieurs.
   >   Je *les* ai fait manger.

   Le pronom *les* est utilisé pour *ces messieurs*, c'est le pronom pour un complément d'objet direct, qui est ici le sujet réel de *manger*.

   On peut s'en exclamer, en raison de la quantité (et en trois niveaux de langue différents) :

   > Qu'est-ce que je les ai fait manger !
   >   **Ce que je les ai fait manger !**
   >   Que les ai-je fait manger !

Comment: Dire que "Ce que je les ai fait manger !" est correct semble un peu capilotracté. C'est au mieux une ellipse de "Qu'est-ce que je les ai fait manger !".

Comment: @Bruno: Je ne crois pas, mais on peut le faire précéder par *C'est fou* si tu préfères, et là je ne pense pas que ce soit sujet à débat.

Comment: En fait, je voulais juste dire que "*Ce que je les ai fait manger !*" sonnait moins correct mais c'est surtout plus familier je pense, tu as raison. (Ça sonne mieux précédé d'un juron, d'ailleurs :-) )

Answer (score 5):

> Ce que je leur ai fait manger.

est correct.

Si le contexte est « je parle du dîner que j'ai servi à mes amis hier », on dit souvent

> Ce que je leur ai fait *à* manger.

Comment: En effet, *faire manger quelque chose à quelqu'un* sous-entend souvent « de force ». C'est plus convivial de faire « à manger », expression qui s'emploie pour la préparation d'un repas.